# How does Quora find a correct resource to request of the url slug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, seo, search-engine, slug

### How does Quora find a correct resource to request of  the url slug ( Question, User, or Topic )?

For example:

http://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-rewrite-their-urls

As you can see, the URL for a question does not have a controller's name. It is associated with the root URL. How can I do this in ASP.NET MVC 3 ?

Comment: I think you'll find you'll get much better responses if you ask a question that directly relates to something you've tried to code and failed at.  Why don't you ask the question in terms of what *you* want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the Quora developers answered your question on the site: http://www.quora.com/How-does-Quora-rewrite-their-urls

> We don't use Apache or anything with "rewrite rules". We have code that takes a question's text, strips out special characters, replaces spaces with dashes, and turns it into a URL. We store the URL for each question so that we can do a reverse lookup when a new request for a page comes in.

If you want to do the same thing in MVC (or ASP.NET), I would think you have to write your own HTTP handler. I don't have any examples handy but you can Google it or check MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx)